# Position of UIView in ScrollView is wrong

Tags: swift, layout

I tried to add 4 views to scrollview to create horizontal paging view. 
But I don't understand why between each view have white space which width equal width of each view. They should be close together.

```
walkthroughItems = {
        let width = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width
        let height = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height
        return [
            WalkthroughItem0(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width,height: height)),
            WalkthroughItem1(frame: CGRect(x: width, y: 0, width: width,height: height)),
            WalkthroughItem2(frame: CGRect(x: width * 2, y: 0, width: width,height: height)),
            WalkthroughItem3(frame: CGRect(x: width * 3, y: 0, width: width,height: height))
        ]
    }()
for item in walkthroughItems {
    scrollView.addSubview(item)
}
scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width*4, height: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height)
```

Comment: Have you tried using the "Debug -> View Debugging -> Show View Frames" or the "Debug -> View Debugging -> Capture View Hierarchy" to check if some of the content on your `WalkthroughItem`s might cause the problem?